# confused about scala function literal

Tags: scala, function

I confuse why the stringop3 is error. If I want to define value stringop3 has two params, one is a:String, the other is f:String=>String , what should I do.

```
// right
def stringop (a:String)(f:String=>String) = f(a)
// right
val stringop2=((a:String),(f:String=>String))=>f(a)
// error
val stringop3=(a:String)(f:String=>String)=>f(a)
```

the error is :
error: not a legal formal paramete
r.

Note: Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters.

Either create a single parameter accepting the Tuple1,

or consider a pattern matching anonymous function: `{ case (param1, param1
) => ... }

val stringop3=(a:String)(f:String=>String)=>f(a)

```
                      ^
```

one error found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curried function definitions (eg: `fn(a: A)(b: B): C`) can be visualised as fn: A => B => C.

So, you can define your stringops3 like this:

```
scala> val stringops3 = (a:String) => (f: String => String) => f(a)
stringops3: String => ((String => String) => String) = <function1>

scala> stringops3("foo")(_.toUpperCase)
res1: String = FOO
```